# Why does Convert.ToDouble(string) round?

Tags: .net, string

For example, Convert.ToDouble("0.1234567890123456789") = 0.123456789012346

What is the maximum number of significant figures?  Couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.71).aspx):

Precision: 15-16 digits.

Answer (score 7):

Of course there's a maximum precision.  It's the maximum that you can express with the bits used to store the double.  For that string you might try Decimal instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to understand binary representation of floating point numbers, see [IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) on Wikipedia.

Basically, it's

`sign * 1.mantissa * 2^(exponent - bias)`

The number of bits allocated to the mantissa and exponent fields determines the precision of the number.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision

A double only has 64 bits of storage, and some of them are used for the sign and exponent, so there are a limited number of digits (usually 15) for the fractional part. A float has only 32 bits, so 8-9 digits of precision. Also some numbers cannot be represented exactly using a floating point number so you may see some rounding errors in your conversions.

Comment: According to MSDN, a .NET float gets 7 digits of precision.

Comment: A `double` has 53 bits (15.95 digits) of precision, while a `float` has 24 bits (7.22 digits).